# how to put values in arrays in for clause?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

so this is 'userclass' column in user table(associated with curriculum table):
[image: poor me no reps]

and this is the class list in curriculum table:
[image: poor me no reps2]

and I would like to put class ids of each user in an array like this:

[image: poor me no reps3]

and the code looks like this:

```
let usernCurr = await User.findAll({
  attributes: ['username', 'userclass'],
  where: {
    userclass: {
      [Op.ne]: null
    }
  }
})

console.log(usernCurr)

for (let i = 0; i < usernCurr.length; i++) {
  let personalCurrList = [];
  usernCurr[i].dataValues.userclass.split(' ').forEach(v => {
    personalCurrList.push(v)
  })
  // console.log('personalCurrlist다.',personalCurrList)

  let array1 = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < personalCurrList.length; j++) {
    // console.log(personalCurrList[i][j])

    let asdf = await Curriculum.findOne({
      attributes: ['id', 'subject'],
      where: {
        id: personalCurrList[j]
      }
    })
    // console.log(`${asdf[0].dataValues.subject}`)
    array1.push(asdf.dataValues.subject);
    // console.log('array1이다',array1)
  }
  console.log(array1)
}
```

and ultimately I want to use the arrays for rendering a page using nunjucks.

I have tried many times and apparently putting array1 in the middle of for clause is the only way that works properly for now.

is there a way to make arrays like that in the black background pic out of the for clause?
or is there a way to render one single page in the for clause?

Comment: you don't need the `forEach` loop, you can just assign the result of `split()` to the variable. You're just making an unnecessary copy of the array.

Comment: You shouldn't use delimited lists in a table column. If you normalize the `userclass` table you can just join the two tables to get what you want, instead of using nested loops.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?